# Find a file beginning with a string but having a specific extension

Tags: command-line, files

It doesn't work if I do this:

```
string*.extension
```

How do I do this?

I want to rename a file that has a specific beginning, but is completely random after that, but has a specific extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`, searching recursively from the current directory:

```
find . -type f -name 'start*.ext' -exec mv -i {} foobar.txt \;
```

Assuming the file name starts with `start` and has an extension `.ext`, renaming the file to `foobar.txt`. Replace these to meet your need.

Searching non-recursively:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'start*.ext' -exec mv -i {} foobar.txt \;
```

Note that, to rename a bunch of files to specific patterns, the approach will be a different; The above procedure is for finding-renaming a single file to something fixed as you have mentioned in the question.

---

As you want to just rename the file, you can use `rename` (`prename`) too:

```
rename -n 's/^start.*?\.ext$/foobar.txt/' *.*
```

`-n` will do the dry-running, to perform the actual action remove `-n`:

```
rename 's/^start.*?\.ext$/foobar.txt/' *.*
```

Comment: I can't get the first example to work in perl if the filename has an apostrophe. I can't get the second example to work at all with apostrophes in the name, even if I escape them with a backslash. It just creates a new line in my terminal.

Comment: Eh, I just changed the single quotes for the argument in the -name switch to double quotes, and all is fine now.